# Minimum characters for a text field? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I´m currently working on a login and registration(Xcode 7, Swift2). If a user registers and types his desired username in the text field,i would like him to type at least 5 characters. So if he leaves the text field and haven´t typed in at least 5 characters, a message get´s displayed that tells him to type in at least 5 characters.
I only found how to determine the maximum amount of characters, but was not able to adjust it to my needs.
This is my current code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    // Mark: Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var Username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var Status: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var DesiredUsername: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Mark: Actions

    @IBAction func CreateAccount(sender: UIButton) {
    }
    @IBAction func LoginButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

        if (Username.text == "janoschvongehr" && Password.text == "test123") {
          performSegueWithIdentifier("SeguetoPeople", sender: nil)
        }

        if (Username.text == "" || Password.text == "") {
        Status.text = "Nicht alle Felder ausgefüllt"
        }

        self.Username.resignFirstResponder()
        self.Password.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }


}
```

I just started with programming, so it would be great if you could keep the answers as simple as possible. 
Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField.text!.characters.count < 5 {
         warningLabel.hidden = false
    }
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return true
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Almost there! But I still get the issue "Invalid redeclaration of textFieldShouldReturn"

Comment: Just named it textFieldShouldReturn2,now I don´t have any issues displayed. But the warning label is always visible, whether I type in nothing, less than 5 characters or more than 5 characters.

Comment: do you have another textFieldShouldReturn method in the class somewhere?

Comment: No, but the issue is gone anyway. The problem I have is, that the warning label is never hidden, no matter how many characters I type in.

Comment: if textField.text!.characters.count < 5 { warningLabel.hidden = false } else { warningLabel.hidden = true } how about that?

Comment: No, still always visible :/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are 90% of the way there, especially in the fact you already set a delegate for your text field.

Try doing:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if ( textField.text.count < 5 )
        {
             // create a warning label IBOutlet and set it to hidden
             //
             // reveal it only upon leaving the text field when the
             // length is less than 5
             warningLabel.hidden = false;
        }
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }
```

Comment: I created a warning label and tried the following:  `func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if (DesiredUsername.text.length < 5 )
        {
            // create a warning label IBOutlet and set it to hidden
            //
            // reveal it only upon leaving the text field when the
            // length is less than 5
            warninglabel.hidden = false;
        }
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }` but now i get two issues: "invalid redeclaration of textfieldshouldreturn" and "value of type string? has no member length"

Comment: Whoops... you need to use `count` and not `length` to get the number of characters in that text field.  Also, do you have `textFieldShouldReturn` declared twice in your view controller?

Comment: Yes,i declared `textFieldShouldReturn` already for `func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }`

Comment: In addition, i get the issue "count is unavailable: there is no universally good answer, see the documentation comment for discussion". This is my current code: `func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if ( textField.text!.count < 5 )
        {
                       // reveal it only upon leaving the text field when the
            // length is less than 5
            warninglabel.hidden = false;
        }
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }
`